# Is addition associative so we don't need brackets

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

Is ($a-b)+(c-b)=-2b+a+c$ ?

So if I have the following operation

$$\dot{x_1}(t) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - x_1)}$$

Can I write

$$\dot{x_1}(t) =- nx_1 +\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)$$

Comment: What is this title supposed to be? Yes you can remove the constant term from the sum.

Comment: I want to know if the two terms are equivalent. so Can I simply remove the brackets

Comment: What makes $(a-b)+(c-b)=-2b+a+c$ isn't associativity alone, but associativity together with commutativity. Associativity implies that the following five quatities are the same: 1) $(a-b)+(c-b)$; 2) $a+(-b+(c-b))$; 3) $a+((-b+c)-b)$; 4) $((a-b)+c)-b$; 5) $(a+(-b+c))-b$.

Comment: Yes you can write $\displaystyle\dot{x_1}(t) =- nx_1 +\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)$